# Cannot import database models in interactive terminal within Flask app context

Tags: python

I'm trying to test my database how it behaves in a many-to-many relationships. I'm struggling to access the application context of the Flask app.

I ran the Python terminal in the parent folder of the app and followed the steps found on SO and elsewhere. I could manage (i think) to import the app, create it, push the context, import the db. However, whenever I want to import models I'm prompted with a:

`Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'db'`

Despite the fact that db is definately defined:
[image]

This is the screenshot of the complete process.

[image]

The folder structure is:

```
- app
--__int__.py
```

This is the app/**init**.py file:

```
from flask import Flask,Blueprint
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app.config import Config
from mailjet_rest import Client

db = SQLAlchemy()
mailjet = Client(auth=(Config.MJ_APIKEY_PUBLIC, Config.MJ_APIKEY_PRIVATE), version='v3.1')

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    
    db.init_app(app)
    
    from app.views.users import users
    from app.views.data import data
    from app.views.admin import admin
    app.register_blueprint(users,url_prefix='/users')
    app.register_blueprint(data,url_prefix='/data')
    app.register_blueprint(admin,url_prefix='/admin')

    # with app.app_context():
    #     db.create_all()

    return app
```

I'd greatly appreciate any input!

Thank you,
Matija

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: @UmairMubeen the version if 3.7

Comment: okay which database are you using and module name?

Comment: It's SQLite. Models are defined in app/models.py while the configuration is in app/config.py @UmairMubeen

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite simple. I ought to import models from `app.models` and not from db.

The steps I took:

1. Rename the folder to app
2. Ran Flask shell command on the app level
3. Imported app
4. Import models from app.models